# How do I access an android phone's filesystem from the command line?

Tags: linux, filesystems, android

When I plug my phone (a Moto G XT1032) into a computer running Fedora Core 24 / MATE:

A file manager (Caja) pops up showing the phone's filesystem.

The address in the browser is `mtp://[usb:001,074]/`

but:

```
$ ls mtp://[usb:001,074]/
```

gives:

```
ls: cannot access 'mtp://[usb:001,074]/': No such file or directory
```

What is going on, and how do I mount the filesystem so that I can run grep and find and such on it?

Comment: I have no experience with MTP but [this site](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MTP) looks promising. There are several FUSE tools described there.

Comment: If it's connected in MTP, it should be mountable the same way you'd mount and access any portable storage device such as a USB key.